# How to get the DDL of a select query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible to get the DDL for a query, instead of just a table? A shortened (fictitious) example of what I'd like to do:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         description
    FROM person
    JOIN meta ON meta.person_id = person.id
)
```

The reason I want to do this, is that I have to migrate and wrangle a lot of data to a new database system, and while working this out I have to (re)make a lot of temporary tables in my new database. I would like not to have to figure out the create table command by hand everytime.

Comment: [Do you mean this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-table/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's not what the question is about.  The OP wants to generate a create table statement based on a select query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had an idea that I was not getting the full story :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the closest thing to what you want might be to create the temporary tables using the select you have in mind, then use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS (
    SELECT id, name, description
    FROM person p
    JOIN meta m ON m.person_id = p.id
);
```

And then:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE temp;
```

If you don't really want the table, possibly due to space considerations, then use a `LIMIT` trick to create a one record table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS (
    SELECT id, name, description
    FROM person p
    JOIN meta m ON m.person_id = p.id
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Then, drop the temporary table after you have copied the DDL.

Comment: Well yeah that could work. However I would like to prevent creating stuff in the current database, if possible. Since it is a production database, I have set up a read-only connection, just to be safe. I was hoping for a more direct solution, which I thought possible because in my gui (DBeaver) I accidentally stumbled upon a button to create a DDL somewhere when migrating stuff, but it is hidden very deep...

Comment: @wouthoekstra Maybe use `LIMIT 1` in the select to avoid actually populating the temp table with data.

Comment: Apparantly the temporary table is no issue for a read-only connection. Makes sense,  since these tables exists only for the current connection (I had to read that up). So apart from having to use a couple of steps (e.g. removing the temp table constantly when updating the query) it is a pretty okay solution. I probably can use the LIMIT 1 to reduce the time the query takes if it becomes to complex.